# SQL server Service Accounts permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, logins, service-accounts

I will be changing the existing SQL Server Service accounts from the default to Domain accounts from the SSCM which i believe will set all the required permission. One thing I am not sure whether the service account needs to be added as database logins and if so what are the minimum permission needed.

Comment: Unless you have some specific task with that login, it does not needs to be added as login into SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification...

Comment: @shanky - does running ssis package via sql agent job qualify as a task that you refer to in your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're changing the **SQL Server Agent Service**, make sure you observe this orientation about [SQL Server Role Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/select-an-account-for-the-sql-server-agent-service?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-role-membership) from the doc:

> The account that the SQL Server Agent service runs as must be a member
>   of the following SQL Server roles:
>
> - The account must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.
> - To use multiserver job processing, the account must be a member of    the msdb database role TargetServersRole on the master server.

Also, the [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15) doc should give you information about each SQL Server Service.

---

You already mentioned you're going to use SSCM to do the change, but since it could be useful to others, I believe it's worth mentioning that it's recommended to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to [Change the Service Startup Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-change-the-service-startup-account?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of services.msc. Pinal Dave's article explain a few reasons for [Why to Use SQL Server Configuration Manager Over Services applet (services.msc)?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/03/05/use-sql-server-configuration-manager-services-applet-services-msc-interview-question-week-112/)